# How can i add additional terms in the ElasticSearch Aggregation with Datetime Buckets?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elastic Search 5.3 aggregation api - unable to write a query which calculates a measure on a date bucket- week split by Dimension/ term/field. i am able to make the date buckets and get the measure calculated for that bucket, but unable to split it down by a term: say application or term say transaction. Elastic search 5+ version has deprecated a lot of APIs from previous versions. here is what i got - this is right now aggregating the measure across all terms for that date bucket. Need to split it by some fields / terms. How do I go about doing it.

```
 POST /index_name/_search?size=0 
{ 
    "aggs": {
    "myname_Summary": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "week"
        , "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
         , "time_zone": "-04:00"
      },
        "aggs":{ "total_volume" : {"sum": {"field": "volume"}}
      }

}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "myname_Summary": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "week",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "time_zone": "-04:00"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "split": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "application",
                        "size": 10
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "transaction": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "transaction",
                                "size": 10
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "total_volume": {
                                    "sum": {
                                        "field": "volume"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @user3775217, the split terms is giving me a separate list of doc_counts per app. not the total volume. "aggregations": { "myname_Summary": { "buckets": [ { "key_as_string": "2017-03-13", "key": 1489377600000, "doc_count": 1101400, "total_volume": { "value": 285977085 }, "split": { "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 652, "sum_other_doc_count": 35778, "buckets": [ {"key": "app2", "doc_count": 671680 }, { "key": "app1", "doc_count": 185564 }...

Comment: can you post the json on how you want the result to be?

Comment: something like this: 
"aggregations": {
    "myname_summary": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-03-13",
          "key": 1489377600000,
          "doc_count": 1101400,
 [{"my_app":app1,
 "my_transaction":"txn1",
          "total_volume": {
            "value": 2859
          }},
 {"my_app":app2,
 "my_transaction":"txn1",
          "total_volume": {
            "value": 1857
          }},
 {"my_app":app3,
 "my_transaction":"txn1",
          "total_volume": {
            "value": 1659
          }}
        }
      ]
    }
  }

Comment: ok so you want to get aggregate(sum on volume by application). i cannot give you exact json structure you mentioned but this will give you exact correct metrics. I have edited by answer.

Comment: now I am getting empty bucket array:aggregations": {
    "myname_Summary": {
      "buckets": []
    }

Comment: can you post your sample json documents as i am getting proper results using the above query. also recheck if you are aggregating on proper fields with proper intervals

Comment: without the date histogram portion if I simply try the rest - consisting of aggs for app and transaction for volume- that split is working, but if I include the date_histogram part it is giving me blank- xcludedate_result - "aggregations": {"split": {  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 510, "sum_other_doc_count": 38868,"buckets": [{ "key": "app1","doc_count": 529133,
          "transaction": { "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 36013,
            "buckets": [{"key": "Txn1",
                "doc_count": 201328,
                "total_volume": { "value": 191}}

Comment: sorry , just noticed that you edited , tried that it works now. what is the change?, I am trying to understand how it worked.

Comment: Just noticed the timestamp-  :) timestamp field was missing, so it was working from before ... you were right. @user3775217 thank you so much for helping me, got a very good understanding of the aggregation API.

Comment: that field i changed to run query on my local as i had a different name for the field and i copied pasted the same without changing w tthe field. Regarding how this worked is you need to observe the nested aggregations levels that i changed. if am first grouping the documents based on date for weekly interval, then furthur i am grouping each date interval bucket based on application, which is furthur grouped based on transaction. Finally for each bucket in transaction i am doing summation on volume. So this is typically drilled down aggregations.

Comment: I was also trying to see if I can do max(volume) , say , just like , sum(volume) above... at the same level in addition to existing measure - volume. Its tricky as aggs cant take 2 aggs in one level. Then it gives me the latest aggs only. trying out and Reading up to see if arrays in aggs[]  can be used for this.

Comment: aggs do take multiple aggs on same level

Comment: but i think the query above pretty much solve your usecase